# What order do switch statements with when clauses get evaluated?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Consider the following example:

```
public static double ComputeArea_Version3(object shape)
{
    switch (shape)
    {
        case Square s when s.Side == 0:
        case Circle c when c.Radius == 0:
            return 0;

        case Square s:
            return s.Side * s.Side;
        case Circle c:
            return c.Radius * c.Radius * Math.PI;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(
                message: "shape is not a recognized shape",
                paramName: nameof(shape));
    }
}
```

Is the `when` clause `case Square s when s.Side == 0:` guaranteed to execute before the more generic `case Square s:`? What determines that order, position within the `switch`? If I were instead write:

```
public static double ComputeArea_Version3(object shape)
{
    switch (shape)
    {
        case Square s:
            return s.Side * s.Side;
        case Circle c:
            return c.Radius * c.Radius * Math.PI;

        case Square s when s.Side == 0:
        case Circle c when c.Radius == 0:
            return 0;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(
                message: "shape is not a recognized shape",
                paramName: nameof(shape));
    }
}
```

Would the `when` clauses never be evaluated?

Comment: You are already calling the `return` line, so it would not reach the succeeding case statements.

Comment: I think he is asking if they would go in order when the cases aren't being met. He wants to know if the conditions are evaluated in order. The answer is yes, the cases are considered in the order they are supplied.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cases clauses are evaluated in the order indicated by the code.

A switch is no more than a succession of if then else if then else and so on, in a concise and more readable matter.

So it breaks the parsing at the first true condition if you put a break or return or a throw or a goto statement else they are checked in succession as well.

For example you can write:

```
case 0:
case 1:
  DoSomething();
  break;
```

But you can't write:

```
case 0:
  DoSomething();
  // break or return or throw or goto needed here
case 1:
  DoAnotherSomething();
  break;
```

You can debug line by line with some sample to check that.

Your second sample does not compile because conditions must be put from specific to general.

Example:

```
object instance = new Form();
switch ( instance )
{
  case Form f when f.Text == "Test":
    return;
  case Form f:
    return;
  case Label l:
    return;
}
```

IL code generated:

```
// object obj = new Form();
IL_0001: newobj instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Form::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
// object obj2 = obj;
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: stloc.s 7
// object obj3 = obj2;
IL_000a: ldloc.s 7
IL_000c: stloc.1
// if (obj3 == null)
IL_000d: ldloc.1
// (no C# code)
IL_000e: brtrue.s IL_0012

// }
IL_0010: br.s IL_002c

// if ((form = (obj3 as Form)) == null)
IL_0012: ldloc.1
IL_0013: isinst [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Form
// (no C# code)
IL_0018: dup
IL_0019: stloc.2
IL_001a: brfalse.s IL_0020

IL_001c: br.s IL_002e

IL_001e: br.s IL_0048

// if ((label = (obj3 as Label)) != null)
IL_0020: ldloc.1
IL_0021: isinst [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label
// (no C# code)
IL_0026: dup
IL_0027: stloc.3
IL_0028: brfalse.s IL_002c

IL_002a: br.s IL_004f

IL_002c: br.s IL_0056

// Form form2 = form;
IL_002e: ldloc.2
IL_002f: stloc.s 4
// if (!(form2.Text == "Test"))
IL_0031: ldloc.s 4
IL_0033: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::get_Text()
IL_0038: ldstr "Test"
IL_003d: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
// (no C# code)
IL_0042: brtrue.s IL_0046

IL_0044: br.s IL_001e

IL_0046: br.s IL_0056

// Form form3 = form;
IL_0048: ldloc.2
IL_0049: stloc.s 5
// (no C# code)
IL_004b: br.s IL_004d

IL_004d: br.s IL_0056

// Label label2 = label;
IL_004f: ldloc.3
IL_0050: stloc.s 6
// (no C# code)
IL_0052: br.s IL_0054

IL_0054: br.s IL_0056

IL_0056: ret
```

As you can see, this code is a succession of tests and branchings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes

Comment: I don't think in general your answer is true. It is my understanding that C# has the ability to generate a hash table for constant value `switch` statements, which should render the ordering mute.

Comment: It will only generate a dictionary for >7 cases. The ordering is `moot` regardless, though

Comment: I did not know the compiler would produce an error `The switch case has already been handled by a previous case.` in the second example. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions) confirms that the order is as it is written in the code:

> The switch expressions are evaluated in textual order. Execution
>   transfers to the first switch label that matches the switch
>   expression.

While it is correct that your second example wouldn't compile as @OlivierRogier explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772446), order still matters. Consider this code snippet:

```
object o = 42;

switch (o)
{
   case int i when i > 10:
       Console.WriteLine("Greater 10");
       break;
   case int j when j > 20:
       Console.WriteLine("Greater 20");
       break;
}
```

This will print `Greater 10`. But if you switch (no pun intended) the two cases to

```
switch (o)
{
   case int j when j > 20:
       Console.WriteLine("Greater 20");
       break;
   case int i when i > 10:
       Console.WriteLine("Greater 10");
       break;
}
```

it will still compile but print `Greater 20`.

Comment: It is important to explain when does this compilation error appear:"The switch case has already been handled by a previous case."

Comment: Fun fact you can repeat identical `case when` and the compiler will not care as it only checks if there is a `case` that already covers a `case when`, but doesn't really inspect the `when` part.